# How to pass arguments to the pre-build command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build

How do I pass arguments to a Pre-build event command line in Visual Studio 2013?

I can run the program with `"C:\foo\bar.exe"` but can't pass arguments to my program.
I have tryed difference combinations like.

1)

"c:\foo\bar.exe"

"c:\sourcepath\"

"c:\targetpath"

2)

"c:\foo\bar.exe -c:\sourcepath\ c:\targetpath"

3)

"c:\foo\bar.exe c:\sourcepath\ c:\targetpath"

4)

"c:\foo\bar.exe -c:\sourcepath\, c:\targetpath"

5)

"c:\foo\bar.exe c:\sourcepath\, c:\targetpath"

Maybe it's not possible? I can't find anything in the doc [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx).

Comment: were you able to sort that out?

Comment: Nope. I does it manually now. I can't remember if it was me that did something wrong or the thirdpart program "bar.exe" that didn't take the parameters in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly that you want variables passed automatically when you compile and run your project, it is possible in the project settings.

Go to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties

Fill out the Command Arguments field with whatever you want to automatically pass when you run it in MSVS.

Comment: I want to run another program i made, with some arguments, before i run my "big" program. What you are saying is how to add arguments to the "big" program right? Or do i misunderstand you?

Comment: You can find the "Pre-build event command line" under project properties > "Build Events"

Comment: Your question is not clear. How are you calling to run the other programs?

Comment: I added a comment above your question ^^

Comment: So, you can't find that, or what am I missing?

Comment: I can find it. And I can run my .exe with "c:\foo\bar.exe" but I can't pass any arguments to the bar.exe program, so it can use the arguments(which are a sourcePath and a targetPath). I don't want the program to have those paths hardcoded.

Comment: I think I found it. Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Build Events. Is that what you're looking for? I've never used it before.

Comment: You are back to my original question now :)

Comment: Well, I'll leave this here for now so people know what you don't want. :) Hopefully Rolo will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. "c:\foo\bar.exe" c:\sourcepath\ c:\targetpath
2. "c:\foo\bar.exe" "c:\sourcepath\path with space" "c:\targetpath"

You should not put all the command between quotes, use quotes for the executable and it is always recommended to use quotes for your arguments if they contain spaces.

**Update:**

As I told before, you must surround each path with quotes specially when they have spaces.

Try this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mark Lagendijk\WinLess\WinLess.exe" "d:\udvikling\test_winless\LESS\factory\" "D:\Udvikling\test_winless\LESS"

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mark Lagendijk\WinLess\WinLess.exe
d:\udvikling\test_winless\LESS\factory\
D:\Udvikling\test_winless\LESS"

Comment: That is my three arguments I want to pass to my "c:\foo\bar.exe"